# Piping to another program in the middle of a oneliner

Tags: bash, pipe, unity, xclip

I'm trying to create a simple bash one line script that allows me to pick a particular barcode that's visible on my screen and make it available as text on my clipboard. To that effect, I wrote a bash script that aims to capture a part of the screen with `gnome-screenshot` into a PNG file, inspect that file with `zbarimg` and make whatever it outputs available to be pasted with `xclip`.

Here's what I wrote:

```
tfile=$(mktemp -u -p ~).png &&  gnome-screenshot -a -f $tfile &&  zbarimg -q --raw $tfile | xclip; rm $tfile
```

Just after I run this script it does request me to capture a part of the screen (exactly what `gnome-screenshot` is supposed to do), the screenshot file is created, but after that it seems that `xclip` runs and waits for input forever, as if `zbarimg` didn't output anything.

Does anyone have a suggestion to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you try to pipe to tee like `...|tee >(xclip) |...` ...?/

Comment: I don't think tee is necessary here but its ambiguous what the asker tried. It involves piping but its not shown in the command. Further what does exit cleanly or not mean?

Comment: The issue might be that zbarimg didn't find anything so when doing `zbarimg -q --raw $tfile | xclip` The use of -q on zbarimg results it doing nothing and xclip waits for input forever?

Comment: Fixed the missing pipe. Sorry.

Comment: There are at least three parts to any useful bug report or even any trouble statement: what you did *exactly,* what results you expected or desired, and what results you got instead.  "Was not able to make the script work properly" doesn't give any clue as to what happened *instead* of what you wanted.  Please **edit your question** to clarify.

Comment: Good fix, you got my reopen vote (5 are needed, now you have 2).

Comment: What happens if you run the command up to (but ***not*** including) the **`|`**? I.e., just run ```zbarimg``` with output to the terminal?

Comment: I'm a little bit confused now since I'm not being able to reproduce the issue in a machine I have (an Ubuntu), neither in another one (a Debian). I noticed the issue in a third machine (an older Ubuntu) that is currently inaccessible to me. Could it be a problem with the installed packages?

Answer (score 0):

for mouse middle button click:

```
tfile=$(mktemp -u -p ~).png &&  gnome-screenshot -a -f $tfile ; cat <(zbarimg -q --raw $tfile) | xclip ; rm $tfile
```

for mouse right button click:

```
tfile=$(mktemp -u -p ~).png &&  gnome-screenshot -a -f $tfile ; cat <(zbarimg -q --raw $tfile) | xclip -selection clipboard ; rm $tfile
```

Comment: Can you explain how your code works? Also, since you presumably solved the user's issue, can you explain what the actual issue was? This would help the user understand what was wrong and why your answer is correct. You seem to have replaced `zbarimg -q --raw $tfile` with functionally equivalent command and you run that command unconditionally instead of in an AND-list. I'm guessing it's taking the command out of the AND-list that mattered, right?

Comment: I'm not sure why this happens but i did some tests and found that "uptime | xclip" worked, so I excluded xclip bugs. Trying the same thing with zbarimg I saw xclip didn't receive expected input so i tried to redirect stderr to stdout (zbaring 2>&1) but I had same problem. On the other hand syntax <(zbarimg) results in a called process substitution and provides a way to pass the output of a command (zbarimg) to another command when using a pipe (|) is not possible: in this way cat command "(cat <(zbarimg -q --raw $tfile)" shows the zbarimg output content and piping it to xclip does the job